# Problems with height:100% on image

Tags: html, css, height

anyone know how to solve this problem:

The image of the example overboard the image-wrapper that contain it.
It works correctly if it's smaller or change "max-height:40vw" to "height:40vw", but both solutions are bad for me.

What I'm trying it's to get that image responsive in different resolutions ( desktop to laptop, for mobile I have a different design ), like here: http://goo.gl/yRo5OE (deviantart)

The website where I'm trying to implement: http://goo.gl/AAF4U7

Thank you, if you have another solution for this please tell me.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  max-height:40vw;
  background:#141414;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  height:100%;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://webbiter.com/project/tattoobiter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/skull-with-rose.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Why are they bad? What are you trying to achieve? The DeviantArt image uses JavaScript, by the way.

Comment: Thank for answer!
With "height:40vw" little images go 40vw of height. In this site will be opened the user image submitting and can't control the images quality...
and the other solution it's not good because I can't use only small images..

I don't understand why my image is protrudes with the "max-height" on the container..

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `height:100%` from css

```css
.image-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  max-height:40vw;
  background:#141414;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="http://webbiter.com/project/tattoobiter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/skull-with-rose.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: This distorts the image.

Comment: Thanks for answer!
As GolezTrol says, in the snippet image is distorted, In my website this is the result: http://webbiter.com/project/tattoobiter.com/?p=75

Answer (score 0):

Please see if the following helps-

1. `img{max-width:100%; width:auto; vertical-align: top;}`

   **OR**
2. http://jsbin.com/guwicolora/edit?output

Comment: The first don't work and the second works but don't maintain the width proportion. I worked for all day, maybe tomorrow will solve this. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexFlorentin width proportion??

Comment: @AlexFlorentin Do keep in mind that the `<section>` tag should be directly enclosed by the `<body>` tag, which means , all content should be placed inside the `<section>` tag. Some more changes should do it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem.
The solution:

.image-wrapper {
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 height:43vw;
 padding:40px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.image-wrapper img {
width:auto;
max-height:100%;
} 

How little images it's shows: http://webbiter.com/project/tattoobiter.com/?p=96
How big images it's shows: http://webbiter.com/project/tattoobiter.com/?p=75

Comment: @AlexFlorentin consider adding this as an answer to the question. Might help others in the future.